# Converting Formula Cells to Data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a small piece of code that will convert all cells in a worksheet that contain formulas to data.  It does not change data cells or empty cells:

```
Sub ConvertFormulasToData()
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Cells.Value = .Cells.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

It works just fine.  I tried to simplify this by removing the `.Value`:

```
Sub ConvertFormulasToData2()
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Cells = .Cells
    End With
End Sub
```

This does not work well at all.  It appears to clear all the cells in the worksheet.

It seems to me that both programs should work the same because the default property of `Cells` is `Value`

Can anyone explain why the second sub does not work ??

Comment: it is the `.Cells` that are not needed.  `.Value` will do it alone: `.Value = .Value`

Comment: According to [THIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cells) the default of `Range.Cells` is `.Item` not `.Value`.

Comment: WOW even a superduper user like yourself still has questions to be answered

Comment: @PeterH Well.......I still consider myself a Student........

Comment: @ScottCraner  Thank you...........Post an answer and I will accept it.